# How to select the fields to display in alpha biblography?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, bibliographystyle

I'm using the `alpha` bibliography style, but I want to modify it in such a way that the printed citation is shorter (in order to save space in my references). I have a quite large `.bib` files, so modifying all of them one my one is not very efficient. I use it currently as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{} % Remove heading 

\begin{document}

\section{Annex: List of references}
\bibliography{cryptobib/abbrev3,cryptobib/crypto,local}

\end{document}
```

Then, for example using an entry like the following (where all those `crypto` variables come from the `abbrev3` file):

```
@InProceedings{C:ABSV15,
  author =       "Prabhanjan Ananth and
                  Zvika Brakerski and
                  Gil Segev and
                  Vinod Vaikuntanathan",
  title =        "From Selective to Adaptive Security in Functional Encryption",
  pages =        "657--677",
  editor =       crypto15ed,
  booktitle =    crypto15name2,
  volume =       crypto15vol2,
  address =      cryptoaddr,
  month =        crypto15month,
  publisher =    cryptopub,
  series =       mylncs,
  year =         2015,
  doi =          "10.1007/978-3-662-48000-7_32",
}
```

results in reference like the following naturally:

[image]

But instead I want it to be printed as following:

> [ABSV15] Prabhanjan Ananth, Zvika Brakerski, Gil Segev, and Vinod
> Vaikuntanathan. From selective to adaptive security in functional
> encryption. In CRYPTO 2015.

So I only want to keep the author, title and booktitle. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a custom variant of `alpha.bst` called `short_alpha.bst` that seems to work as expected. Here is the [file](https://file.io/NizcihEYzyEz).
Moreover, I had to add the following options to `natbib` for it to work without errors: `\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}`